# javascript single thread makes some calculations impossible

Tags: javascript, multithreading

Considering I'm trying to make an `algorithm` that finds the `least expansive path`.
Every computation of the current path is `async`.
My algorithm just kills the stack. Any other alternative?

The code for what I've been coding is:

```
function DFS(unvisitedNodes, currentVertex, currentRouteFromStart, depth, minimalPath,     finalVertex, maxDepth, doneCallback) {

// Add the final destination to the top of the list.
var copiedUnvisitedVertices = unvisitedNodes.slice(0);
copiedUnvisitedVertices.splice(0, 0, finalVertex);

var i = 0;
var singleIteration = function (i) {
    if (i == copiedUnvisitedVertices.length) {
        doneCallback(minimalPath);
        return;
    }

    if (i > 0) {
        // Putting the check here makes sure we compute the edge 
        // for the last depth for the destination vertex only.
        if (depth == maxDepth) {
            currentRouteFromStart.pop();
            doneCallback(minimalPath);
            return;
        }
    }

    var dest = copiedUnvisitedVertices[i];
    computeEdge(currentVertex, dest, function (edgeInfo) {
        currentRouteFromStart.push(edgeInfo);
        var currentCost = edgeCost(currentRouteFromStart);
        var afterBFSDone = function (_minimalPath) {
            currentRouteFromStart.pop();
            singleIteration(i + 1);
            return;
        }
        if (dest == finalVertex) {

            var minPrice = edgeCost(minimalPath);
            if (currentCost < minPrice) {
                minimalPath = currentRouteFromStart.slice(0);
            }
        }
        else {
            DFS(unvisitedNodes.slice(0).splice(i - 1), dest, currentRouteFromStart, depth + 1, minimalPath, finalVertex, maxDepth, afterBFSDone);
        }

        afterBFSDone(minimalPath);


    });
};
singleIteration(0);

}
```

Comment: First of all, it is my understanding that the maximum stack size depends on the browser on which you execute your code. Secondly, do you really want your algorithm to be executed client-side?

Comment: you can go multi threaded with web works: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers .
Does the iteration contain asyc callback ?

Comment: I'm coding a chrome extension, hence the limitation on javascript (I'm now considering the Native Client), and the async operation talks with open tabs, so yes, clients.

Comment: @KonstantinKrass,  I looked briefly at that, that won't really 'break' the single execution. callbacks will still be called to call the 'post_action' code, and the stack would still get overflown.